# MVC identity changing user roles

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a Vb.net MVC project with single user authentication.  Admins can view all users within a "manager users" page, users are split in to 3 different roles Admin, Employee and User respectively.  I want Admins to be able to promote roles: Users to Employee or Employee to Admin, and also demote.

I thought about adding a button next to each user to either promote or demote.  I'm struggling as to how each button would be linked to each user and how i would post that one user change back to the controller.

Could someone please advise, thanks

UserViewModels.vb

```
Public Class GroupedUserViewModel
   Public Property Users() As List(Of UserViewModel)
   Public Property Admins() As List(Of UserViewModel)
   Public Property Employee() As List(Of UserViewModel)
End Class

Public Class UserViewModel
   Public Property FullName() As String
   Public Property Email() As String
   Public Property RoleName() As String
End Class
```

View:
I'm displaying all Admin, Employee and User roles within the view, here is the admin example:

```
@Modeltype GroupedUserViewModel

 @If Model.Admins.Any Then
    @:<div Class="Rtable Rtable--3cols Rtable--collapse">
        @For Each Admin In Model.Admins
            @:<div Class="Rtable-cell">
            @Admin.FullName
            @:</div>
            @:<div Class="Rtable-cell">
            @Admin.Email
            @:</div>
            @:<div Class="Rtable-cell">
            @Admin.RoleName
            @:</div>
        Next Admin
   @:</div>
End If
```

Comment: Basically you need to send respective action parameters to controller as button clicks such as user id, action(promote , demote). And then add remove from respective list. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to stick with a mostly HTML-based answer, as my VB is rusty. Feel free to substitute the appropriate HTML/URL helpers or whatever you would like.

Basically, you can take one of two approaches:

1. Have a separate form for each button. This makes the most sense if you also have separate actions for each button (i.e. you have a `Promote` action and a `Demote` action on your controller.

   ```
   <form action="/path/to/promote/action" method="post">
       <input type="hidden" name="userId" value="1" />
       <button type="submit">Promote</button>
   </form>
   <form action="/path/to/demote/action" method="post">
       <input type="hidden" name="userId" value="1" />
       <button type="submit">Demote</button>
   </form>
   ```
2. One form with both "Promote" and "Demote" buttons. This obviously makes more sense if you have just one action that will handle both processes.

   ```
   <form action="/path/to/role/change/action" method="post">
       <input type="hidden" name="userId" value="1" />
       <button type="submit" name="promote">Promote</button>
       <button type="submit" name="demote">Demote</button>
   </form>
   ```

   Then, since only the button that is clicked will be included in the post data, you can branch in your action accordingly:

   ```
   If Request.Form["promote"] IsNot Nothing Then
       'promote user
   ElseIf Request.Form["demote"] IsNot Nothing Then
       'demote user
   EndIf
   ```

You could also get fancier and use AJAX to handle this, but this should be enough to get you going.